# Add pagebreaks to each row, but am getting app or object defined error

Tags: excel, vba

```
For i = 1 To LastRow
    If wbkCurBook.Sheets("August FMR").Cells(i, "A").Value = "CTY" Then
            wbkCurBook.Sheets("August FMR").Rows(i).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
    End If
Next i
```

This loop is suppose to check each row if it has a certain string and if it does its supposed to add a page break at that row. It currently is not adding any page breaks when I run the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code tries to  add pagebreak also on the first row and this won't work because it puts page break above currently looked at row. It works for me if the there isn't a CTY value in first row A column.

If it is object defined then you probably didn't set up you  workbook correctly or your LastRow.

```
For i = 1 To LastRow
    If wbkCurBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Value = "CTY" Then
            wbkCurBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual 'add before row
            wbkCurBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(i + 1).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual 'add after row
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: i believe the object is fine because ive used that reference for other parts of the code that works. How would I get it to add after the row?

Comment: You can't specifically do that with another property, but you could just increase row number by one as i have shown in the code.